# Given an elementary set how to obtain an open elementary set containing it whose measure is less than a desired quantity

Tags: measure-theory

The theorem whose proof I have a question about is:

Given an elementary set $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a set that can be represented as at least one finite (pairwise) disjoint union of bounded intervals (open, half open, closed, or singletons) and a countable (finite or denumerable) collection of elementary sets $\{A_n\}$ such that
$$A\subset \bigcup_{n} A_n,$$ then
$$ m'(A)\leq \sum_n m'(A) $$

where $m'(A)=\sum_1^k m(I_j)=\sum_1^k b_j-a_j$ is the measure of elementary sets, i.e. the sum of the measures of the finitely many disjoint intervals $I_j$ that make up $A$. Both are nonnegative and finitely additive.

This is from one of Kolmogorov's real analysis book (although he does it in the plane). In the proof he obtains a closed elementary set $\bar{A}$ such that
$$m'(\bar{A})\geq m'(A) -\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
and eludes to how to obtain one by taking the appropriate closed intervals within the representation of $A$. Then he claims there is "obviously" an open elementary set $\hat{A}_n$ containing $A_n$ for each $n\in \mathbb{B}$ such that 
$$m'(\hat{A}_n)\leq m'(A_n) +\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}.$$

I was able to work out the details to obtain $\bar{A}$. To obtain $\hat{A}_n$ I found a collection of open intervals containing the intervals representing $A$ whose sum of measures satisfied the desired inequality. But the intervals weren't necessarily disjoint so the union failed to represent an elementary set. What is the trick to this "obvious" claim? I feel dumb harping over it but, I would like to be detailed.

Any hints or suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Words such as *question* do not add information to titles. Please [edit] the title so that it better describes the specifics of your question. Do not hesitate to make it longer or include a formula if needed. More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(autocomment)*

Comment: If you have a finite union of open intervals, if the intervals have intersection you can join them to obtain a disjoin union of open intervals.

Comment: I had thought that but how do I get around showing the measure of the new disjoint union is equal to the measure of the nondisjoint union? I can't use the fact that the measure is independent of the disjoint union representation, for the original one that had the desired measure isn't disjoint. But the measures must be equal for they represent the same set.